# How to calculate the dimensions of the bounding box of a .ply file in R?

Tags: r, 3d

I have some .ply files and I need to calculate their length. All the meshes are oriented so that the longitudinal axis is parallel to the z axis of the bounding box.

I haven't been able to find any function that will give back the axis dimensions of the bounding box of a .ply file.

I tried using the rgl package. but it does not read .ply files

Does someone know what function could I use?

Thanks a lot beforehand!

I tired using this script. But it does not work for .ply files.

```
library(rgl)
```

Loading the .ply file:

```
my_ply <- readOBJ("my_file.ply")
```

Getting the z-axis coordinates:

```
z_coords <- my_ply$vb[,3]
```

Calculating the z-axis length:

```
z_length <- diff(range(z_coords))
```

Printing the result:

```
print(z_length)
```

Comment: The **Rvcg** package has a function to read PLY files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand.

The **cgalMeshes** package allows to read a mesh from a PLY file, and it allows to compute the bounding box of the mesh (the smallest isocuboid containing the mesh). Here is an example.

```r
library(cgalMeshes)
# load the cyclide.ply file into a new mesh
mesh <- cgalMesh$new("cyclide.ply")
# compute its bounding box
bbox <- mesh$boundingBox()
# make a mesh of the bounding box in order to plot it
bxmesh <- isoCuboidMesh(bbox[["lcorner"]], bbox[["ucorner"]])
# convert the mesh of the cyclide to a rgl mesh
rmesh <- mesh$getMesh()
# plot the cyclide with its bounding box
library(rgl)
open3d(windowRect = 50 + c(0, 0, 512, 512))
view3d(0, -60)
shade3d(rmesh, color = "gold")
wire3d(bxmesh, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: This helps me a lot, thanks! basically what i would need to know is the length of the longest side of the "bxmesh" I tried this, but it does not work. mbxm <- as.matrix(bxmesh$vb) # calculate the dimensions of the bounding box length <- diff(mbxm[1:2]) width <- diff(mbxm[3:4]) height <- diff(mbxm[5:6]) # print the result print(paste0("Length: ", length)) print(paste0("Width: ", width)) print(paste0("Height: ", height))

Comment: @user21889737 In `bbox` you have `lcorner` and `ucorner` so you can get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to do it in python:

```
import os
import trimesh
folder_path = "C:/..."
# Iterate over files in folder
for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    # Check if file is a PLY file
    if filename.endswith(".ply"):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        # Load mesh from file
        mesh = trimesh.load(file_path)
        # Get bounding box dimensions
        bbox_dim = mesh.bounding_box.extents
        # Print results
        print(f"{filename}: Height={bbox_dim[2]}")
```

It works like a charm!